# Runtime configuration of EventSource guid

Tags: etw, semantic-logging

We have a scenario whereby multiple pre-release versions of an application run in the same environment. The problem we're seeing is that, because our `EventSource` has the same name/guid, we cannot differentiate between logs.

Is it possible to configure the name/guid of the EventSource via config or otherwise at runtime?

We currently have a single-build deployment pipeline, so I don't think a build-time solution would work for us.

Comment: how do you log the events? If you capture them with PerfView, WPR, you also have loader data and FileVrsion information. Here you can look for the file version of your application.

Comment: have you tried the FileVersion correlation?

Answer (score 2):

That is not supported. Some teams do the following: add additional parameter to each event to pass a version/build identifier.

Another potential option would be to create a pre-build task to alter the source code (EventSource implementation) to assign different GUID each build. But in this case that would be hard to work with those logs.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up filtering the observable by process id:

```
int currentProcessId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

new ObservableEventListener()
    .Where(ev => ev.ProcessId == currentProcessId)
    .LogToRollingFlatFile(...);
```

Obviously that won't work once we move out-of-proc, but it's fine for now.